# Redirect in Nginx HTTP to HTTPS with proxy doesn't work

Tags: angular, ssl, nginx, redirect, proxy

I want to make a redirect HTTP to HTTPS with proxy to my Angular app. The HTTP > HTTPS redirect works, but later this the ssl proxy can't reach the Angular app on localhost:4200.

When I set to 80 port only it works.

I also tried to put both with the same server names, proxy in the both servers, etc...

```
server {
listen 80;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

listen 443;
server_name example.com;

ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

ssl on;
ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;

location / {

proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

# Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
proxy_pass          http://localhost:4200;
proxy_read_timeout  90;
proxy_redirect      http://localhost:4200 https://example.com;
}
}
```

Comment: What to you mean with "the ssl proxy can't reach the Angular app on localhost:4200"? Which is the error?

Comment: The redirect happens but after it i have in the browser an error of "connection time out".

Comment: Do you have the port 443 open? Or do you use any firewall?